# Convert certain values in list to int

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists and I want to convert the second value in each list to an int since it is currently a string

```
[['hello','how','are','you','1'],['hello','how','are','you','2']]
```

I am trying to convert index 4 to an int in each list within this larger list but when I do

```
for hi in above:
    int(hi[4])
```

It is just returning the int when I print the list and not the entire list.

Comment: You have to set the list value back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just traverse it and convert it using the `int()` function for every 4th element in every list inside :

```
for li in my_list:
    li[4] = int(li[4])
```

Answer (score 0):

This list comprehension is one way to do it:

```
a_list = [[int(a) if item.index(a) == 4 else a for a in item] for item in a_list]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a_list = [['hello','how','are','you','1'],['hello','how','are','you','2']]
>>> a_list = [[int(a) if item.index(a) == 4 else a for a in item] for item in a_list]
>>> a_list
[['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 1], ['hello', 'how', 'are', 'you', 2]]
>>>
```

Comment: This is pretty inefficient (using .index). Better to enumerate the list if you want to go down this track

Comment: @Agreed. I was not very satisfied with the answer either